# Converting a regular expression to a DFA

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, dfa, computation-theory, nfa

I've been trying to convert the regular expression   [image]

to a non-deterministic finite automata (NFA) first using Thompson's construction, giving:

[image]

, which looks correct.

I am then using subset construction to create the DFA from the NFA, shown here.

[image]

But this does not look correct to me, as for example 0 followed by 0 is not valid according to the DFA I have constructed. I was wondering how should I be modelling the epsilon in the original regular expression, as I have simply treated it as a normal epsilon.

Comment: This belongs to http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your regex misses a parenthesis?

Comment: @Bergi yeah it does. the picture shows the correct regex

Answer (score 0):

A single matches already - thus state B in your diagram for an dfa has to be already an accepting state (just mark it as accepting would not fix it!). I can't reconstruct your ideas, but you should end in something like

```
A --0--> (B)
A --1-->  C
B --0--> (B)
B --1-->  C
C --0--> (B)
C --1-->  C
```

---

If you'll start to think from the other side, the regex `(0|)(0|1)*0` could be simplified by removing the first part `(0|)`. This could be done because `(0|1)` matches everything that `(0|)` will match (and more).
You can see it in your diagram for the nfa, too.

```
S0->S1->S2->S5 === S7->S7->S8->S11
S0->S3->S4->S5 === epsilon
```

Maybe this could help to get your thoughts in the right direction..